# Add cutom button directly to list view after installing managed package

Tags: managed-package, deployment, custom-button, metadata, search-layout

I have created a managed package in which i need to add custom button after installing my managed package to list view of account and lead. I thought it same like static resource, Remote site settings but it is not the same and buttons do not enforced.. I have installed few apps from appExchange in which i observed that list view custom button are directly enforced. I have googled enough but not got any relevant info..please share your knowledge

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "reflect" may be a bit irritating for us, but I think I understood what you mean. Typically to make a button visible on the UI, it is a two step process:

1. Create the button (this you got already)
2. Add it to the *Search Layout* called "List View"

You are speaking about step two and your experience is that it won't be applied automatically after deployment.

Under the hood, you find your Search Layout in the Standard- or Custom Object metadata.

In eclipse you can see that if you add the Metadata Components called "objects - custom" and "objects - standard" to your project. Then you'll get a new folder Objects containing several *.object files e.g. Lead.object or YourCostomObject__c.object. From those files, the UI pulls the information to render a list-button or not. It's `<listViewButtons>` in a section like this:

```
        <searchLayouts>
            <customTabListAdditionalFields>FULL_NAME</customTabListAdditionalFields>
            <customTabListAdditionalFields>LEAD.COMPANY</customTabListAdditionalFields>
            <customTabListAdditionalFields>LEAD.PHONE</customTabListAdditionalFields>
            <listViewButtons>BulkDelete</listViewButtons>
            <lookupDialogsAdditionalFields>FULL_NAME</lookupDialogsAdditionalFields>
            ...
        </searchLayouts>
```

So to get that button visible on the layout, you have to deploy the Object somehow. With standard objects, as far as I know, it's not possible within packages. Custom objects can be included in packages. So if you are installing the package the first time, buttons (for custom object list view) should simply "appear". Probably this behavior you have observed.

Now to "enforce" the button to appear in the UI in not "Best Practice" on Standard Objects (maybe also for Custom Objects in the context of package upgrades). It's a bit like Page Layouts (not mix-up Page-Layouts and Search-Layouts!) - an Admin could have changed it on purpose (e. g. the Admin might have hidden your button again). So it might not be deployed automatically and this step will be expected to be done by the Admin manually on the target Org.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you are trying to create "list" button.  While creating the button choose the third option "list button " in Display Type

Comment: i want to get it reflected it directly on list view after installing my package Manjunath Nimbal